# Proving convergence in quadratic mean of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of random variables. Show that $X_n$ converges to $b$ in quadratic mean if and only if

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E[X_n] = b $$
and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\operatorname{Var}(X_n) = 0.$$

Comment: are you sure that the problem is stated correctly?

Comment: its actually suppose to have the variance = 0

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $\lim_n\mathbb{E}[X_n] = b$ and $\lim_n\text{Var}(X_n) = 0$, then

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[(X_n - b)^2] = &\ \color{blue}{\mathbb{E}[X_n^2]} -2b\mathbb{E}[X_n] + b^2 \\
= &\ \color{blue}{\text{Var}(X_n) + \mathbb{E}[X_n]^2} -2b\mathbb{E}[X_n] + b^2 \\
\to &\ \color{blue}{0 + b^2} -2b^2 + b^2 \\
= &\ 0.
\end{align}

For the other implication you can show that  $\mathbb{E}[(X_n-C)^2]=\mathbb{E}[(X_n-\mathbb{E}[X])^2]+(\mathbb{E}[X]-C)^2$

If $\lim_n\mathbb{E}[(X_n-C)^2]=0 \implies \lim_n\mathbb{E}[(X_n-E[X])^2]=\lim_n(\mathbb{E}[X]-C)^2=0$ because $\mathbb{E}[(X_n-E[X])^2] \geq 0$ and $(\mathbb{E}[X]-C)^2 \geq 0$.

To finish we know that by the continuity of the square root $\lim_n(\mathbb{E}[X]-C)=0$